# Display images outside of an iframe using Colorbox

Tags: jquery, iframe, parent, colorbox

Please see example code I am working with: http://www.christoffah.com/kk/gallery.php

The red and yellow DIVs contain iframes. Clicking a text link in the yellow DIV loads a colorbox photo, but it loads it within the iframe. Targeting parent opens the image on its own, ie the same thing that would happen if you had typed in the URL of a jpg image. Is there any way of getting the image load over the top of the whole webpage?

The reason I am using iframes is because the website I am working on requires two different galleries containing numerous albums in each and I thought iframes would be a good way for the user to navigate the galleries independently of each other - if there is a more efficient way of doing this I am open to suggestions! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i dont see the necessity for the second iframe with the links.

You'll need to use javascript for the linking, since the target attribute does not provide such think as parent targets. See the Javascript `window.parent` object or especally the `window.parent.frames[...].location` property for details.

However from a SEO point of view this cant be good.

edit try:

```
<a ... onclick="parent.$.fn.colorbox({href: this.href}); return false;">
```

Comment: My second iframe has text for now as I'm testing out the plugin, it will eventually look like the first iframe with thumbnails. Each iframe will have next and previous links so the user can look at two galleries in one go. I appreciate this may not be great for SEO but I can't think of another way to go about it..

I've looked into the JS you recommended but I'm unsure how to alter the image URLs to include this syntax. Colorbox FAQ suggests <a onclick='parent.$.colorbox({href:"login.php"}); return false;'>open in parent window</a> but this doesn't seem to work either... please can you advise?

Comment: your approach actually looks good, but you'll need to include the colorbox js in your parent to make this work. see edited question

Comment: Thank you for the code, I've made the change to the same page - it's almost there but doesn't load the next/previous buttons or the background overlay and an instance of colorbox still loads in the iframe. Try "Test Link": http://www.christoffah.com/kk/gallery.php any ideas at all?

Comment: 1. You'll also include the Colorbox css in the parent. 
As for the 2nd instance you'll can detach the script from the iframe as

Comment: Ah! Including the CSS on the parent makes the background appear which is great, but unfortunately it stops the image from showing... I've detached the script from the second instance but every item will need this script, for example if the user clicks the 5th gallery item, the script will need to be in place so that the gallery item is loaded into the parent and not the iframe.